# Removing Ubuntu partition using flash drive (live ubuntu) and install windows

Tags: drivers, grub2, windows, uninstall, amd-graphics

I was using ubuntu 22.04 on ssd and I had removed the ssd and use another ssd with windows installed on it to install gpu drivers.
When I have tried to install amd gpu driver but the installation field and windows kept frozen because there was a problem on gpu. When I tried to use Ubuntu again I can't even root and the message "**clean: */* files */*blocks.**" keep blinking. now, I deleted ubuntu partition using the flash drive(live ubuntu) and now I am trying to install windows but the installation is too slow. I tried  to fix the power problems but nothing change. I wonder if deleting ubuntu partition wasn't correct and it's the reason I can't install windows, can anyone help.

Comment: I don't understand this at all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If your installation of Windows is too slow, then it's a Windows problem, not an Ubuntu problem. Removing the Ubuntu partition has no effect on the installation speed of Windows. We can't help you with that, Windows problems are off-topic here, sorry.